# How to know total entries of a particular state for all the psu

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

As I am running this query in MySql:

```
select count distinct(prim_key) IN table_1 inner join
table_2 on ID group by column name
```

I want to know total entries of a particular state for all the psu.
the table table_1 tells the total entries by the field agency.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct prim_key) 
from table_1 t1
inner join table_2 t2 on t1.ID = t2.ID
group by state
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this::

```
select 
count (distinct(prim_key))
from table_1 
inner join table_2 on table1.ID=table_2.ID

 group by column name
```